# Print number with spaces as thousands place separator

Tags: php, html, string, reverse

I'm trying to reverse a string and add spaces from 3 in 3 characters the code I have right now is this:

```
$rowPreco = "925000"   
$rowPreco = strrev($rowPreco);
$rowPreco = wordwrap($rowPreco , 3 , ' ' , true );
$rowPreco = strrev($rowPreco);
```

if I take the strrev out it prints how I want ("925 000") but if I have the strrev it will print ("92 500 0").

But I need to use the strrev because if the value is ("1200000") it will print ("120 000 0") instead of ("1 200 000").

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

UPDATE!

When I use the number_format it will ignore a jQuery code that I have.

```
echo "<script>"
          ."jQuery(document).ready(function() {"
          ."var parts = jQuery('.casaPreco').text().split('|');"
          ."jQuery('.casaPreco2').text(parts[4]);"
          ."});"
          ."</script>";
```

Basically the initial string is something like this: "3880562|1|1|925000|||0|0|0"

I need to grab the 4th number so I'm splitting the string on the "|" and use the array parts[4] but when I use the number_format it will grab the number "3880562"

Comment: How does this javascript connected with `number_format`?

Comment: The jquery is inside a document called database.php and I'm including the file in the head

Comment: Once again - __stop__ before you format the value of your number and check it's value.

Comment: You know that indexing starts with 0? How is js-value passed to php?

Comment: Run this in your console also `alert('3880562|1|1|925000|||0|0|0'.split('|')[3]);`

Comment: the alert retrieves the correct value but doesn't print it

Comment: So I'm grabbing $rowPreco from mysql (working), echo it in a div(working), split it thorugh jquery(working), but the spaces between numbers don't work

Comment: I __don't see__ the code how value from js is passed to php.

Comment: I see the problem, it's doing this right now sql -> php -> php -> html -> jquery -> html, and it should be doing sql -> php -> html -> jquery -> html -> php -> html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please do not invent the wheel:

```
echo number_format('925000', 0, '.', ' ');   // 925 000
echo number_format('1200000', 0, '.', ' ');  // 1 200 000
```

[`number_format` manual.](http://php.net/number_format)

Comment: when I try this code if I put the variable $rowPreco inside it will print "3 590 162" when the actual value is 925000

Comment: It's impossible that it will print `3 590 162`. Check `$rowPreco` before keeping it in number_format(). @DiogoAlves

Comment: @DiogoAlves http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/52d70026792e3db057ca645d31f6bd5551d23833

Comment: I will update my question with a the detailed problem